# Wifi tethering on symbian (s60v3)

Tags: symbian, wifi, s60, gprs

Which platform should i choose ?
QT or Symbian C++ ?
Does QT have methods for implementing this ?
How do i make  the phone to behave as a hotspot ?
I'd be grateful if someone point me the right way to get going.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QT is really intended for use in S60v5 devices onwards, support for s60v3 is likely to be limited. I have some QT apps running on my N82 but, to be honest, it's not a great user experience. QT will replace S60 completely at some point (Hooray!). I'd recommend playing with the native Symbian OS APIs.

This might help:
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/SDK_API_Plugin

You may also want to check out the Symbian Foundation message boards:
http://developer.symbian.org/forum/